# WorldPay JSON API - what is the futurepayID

Tags: worldpay

I have integrated the WorldPay JSON API for my client.

They require the futurepayID - **is this is the same as the reusable token that is returned or is the futurepayID a different thing**?

I have tried going through their documentation but it is a little confusing. For reference, I have set reusable to true and everything else works as it should:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
     window.onload = function() {
         Worldpay.useTemplateForm({
             'clientKey':"xxx",
             'form':'paymentForm',
             'saveButton':false,
             'paymentSection':'paymentSection',
             'display':'inline',
             'reusable':true,
             'callback': function(obj) {
                 if (obj && obj.token) {
                     var _el = document.createElement('input');
                         _el.value = obj.token;
                         _el.type = 'hidden';
                         _el.name = 'token';
                         document.getElementById('paymentForm').appendChild(_el);
                         document.getElementById('paymentForm').submit();

                 }
             }
         });
     }
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe you can underline that the question is "**what is futurepayID?**"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I have spoken with WorldPay support and they told me there are two types of gateways - business and online. The business gateway uses futurepayID and uses HTML redirects (payments are taken on their server), whereas the online gateway uses the JSON API and uses tokenisation.

I'm not clear on the difference between the business and online gateways as surely anyone integrating the online gateway would be used by businesses.